# Problems after Windows 7 installation

Tags: windows-7

Some time ago I formatted my PC and installed Windows 7 Ultimate with the correct procedure.

Now when I start it, everything seems good during the boot phase, but then  the screen shows me the Windows 7 logo and then turns off.

The machine start in safe mode, after the installation of Windows nothing changed from the past apart from the impossibility to start the PC.

I tried to restart the installation and repeat the procedure but nothing changed.

I think that could be a problem with drivers.

Do you know any solution?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. We are going to need more information to be able to assist. What changed on the machine prior to this happening? (updates, driver install etc). Does the machine start in safe mode?

Comment: Scuse me , informations are now in the post

Comment: *"The machine start in safe mode"* Do you mean *when I start the machine in safe mode*? *"nothing changed from the past"* Which "past"? Are you just saying that booting into safe mode makes no difference?

Comment: You should remove everything but the most basic hardware, leaving just a system disk and on-board graphics if there is any. Remove all controller cards and reinstall Windows. Then you can create a restore point and add hardware one piece at a time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there is a problem with installation media then no matter how many times you reinstall, it will amount to the same result.

Now, if there is no issue with the installation media then I suggest you boot into Safe Mode to check other you are able to atleast boot into it. Usually if your PC is able to boot into Safe Mode then it will start again on restarting.

Since you already have a windows installation disk/usb, you could try to repair the system. Press F8(again depends on make of PC) at boot to choose Repair option and use your windows media to repair it. If this option too doesn't solve your problem then you could also try checking your HDD for errors by using the chkdsk utility.

This is a link to detailed explanation of above steps, do check if you are not able to solve the problem.

https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/Windows-7-stuck-at-loading-screen.html

Comment: @Riccardo_Fan_98: Please comment to describe how this answer helped you. Stack Overflow is *primarlily* about other people who encounter questions through a web search. You can show your gratitude by making this page more useful to others, which means explaining the problem that you had and how this answer helped you to fix it.